# endtask program using win32api/c like taskmanager to close programs without invoking taskmanager just in one shot

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am using firefox and dreamweaver for my webprojects.
When firefox or dreamweaver is closed they take a long time clearing all the virtual memory and things like that. so mostly i invoke taskmanager and end task firefox and dreamweaver.
I dont have valuable information stored neither in ff nor in dreamweaver so abnormal termination is not a problem i think.

I wanted to write a win32 api program which when executed should find firefox or dreamweaver and should terminate them abruptly like what we do as endtask using taskmanager.

So i want to know where do i have to start in the documentation of windows programing to do some thing like this.

References, suggestions, answers and external links could be useful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing a program in C++, it would be much simpler to write a simple .bat script to kill these processes, using the `taskkill` utility supplied with Windows.  For example.

```
taskkill /im firefox.exe
taskkill /im dreamweaver.exe
```

Comment: Yes. this is working. Yet could you drop me some references of articles or functions related to this login. Even if i could get the working of how taskkill works then i can write my own c program. what i wanted to do is i just want to set some hot keys for each program and i wanted to kill them.

Comment: oh... yeah then can do a shell execute from my c program. isn't it? yeah this is one option i got while commenting the above. yet some windows basics about terminating a task will be nice. i always would like to work with the core. :)

Comment: Call EnumerateProcesses to list the processes. Then call TerminateProcess to kill them.ateProcess to kill them.